# using overlay video filter in ffmpeg guardian project (android)

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

First, im a beginner in FFMPEG so please bear with me.

Im using [this](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java) library and successfully combined an audio and  a video :D

However, i keep failing when i tried to insert an image/watermark over a video.

This is the code im using :

```
public MediaDesc combineVideoAndImage (MediaDesc videoIn, MediaDesc image, MediaDesc out, ShellCallback sc) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();

        cmd.add(ffmpegBin);
        cmd.add("-i");
        cmd.add(new File(videoIn.path).getCanonicalPath());

        cmd.add("-vf");
        cmd.add("movie=" + new File(image.path).getAbsolutePath() + " [logo];[in][logo] overlay=10:10 [out]");

        cmd.add("-strict");
        cmd.add("-2");

        File fileOut = new File(out.path);
        cmd.add(fileOut.getCanonicalPath());

        execFFMPEG(cmd, sc);

        return out;
    }
```

Those code will generate this cmd :

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEONAME.mp4 -vf "movie=LOGONAME.png [logo];[in][logo] overlay=10:10 [out]"
-strict -2 OUTPUTNAME.MP4
```

I have tested this CMD on ubuntu 13.10 64bit, with latest FFMPEG installed and t succeed.

But it does not in my android project. It does not catch/throw any error/exception, the program running normally and **the file is created but has nothing in it (0 byte)**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: up up up up up up up :)

Comment: what ubuntu version ffmpeg worked?  NOTE: https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg/tree/53fc9d4e2972792236d9e4c4c5793322947a884e  following the guardian's extern links takes you to the commit version being used by the android project. Its ffmpeg 0.11 which is a couple years old and is not gonna be the same version as u using on ubuntu.

Comment: @RobertRowntree i have tried to use my own binary, which is the latest version, but still no luck :(

Comment: swapping in a diff ffmpeg version into guardian's project certainly will not work.

Comment: @RobertRowntree why? Cant i just use the proper syntax based on my FFMPEG's version? :D

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: go to github and search on 'android-ffmpeg' and find the version of ffmpeg that is most up to date. Try using that one. The reason you cant just swap in diff versions of ffmpeg is that interface changes affect builds & links.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

i have tested it on android and it is working perfect.